# Adobe Flex/Air Project Importing an .as Class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I've just started looking at basic adobe air apps, however I feel im stuck at the first hurdle.

I've found a action script library for use from http://charlesbihis.github.io/actionscript-notification-engine/

However I'm struggling to figure out how to get the library into Flash Builder 4.7

I've exported my project so you can download and see the errors http://www.mediafire.com/?pu4cm1pndlaxo20

If anybody could share some light/knock up a project file that uses the demo code from the library's webpage that I could look at to see what the hell is going on it would be much appreciated.

many thanks

Owen

Comment: Does this help? https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/12/18/What-do-you-do-with-a-SWC

Comment: It could have been if i had a .swc file, but the git repo only provides a project folder

Comment: You can compile it in your SWC; or add the source code directly to your project.  If you're having specific errors; you really should post them here; not direct people to downloading your project in order to discover them.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that the package name for the library you used is `com.charlesbihis.engine.notification` but you put it simply in `notification`
Meanwhile when writing code inside MXML, consider putting it inside `<![CDATA[`...`]]>` blocks, like this:

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[

// your code goes here

]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: so inside my "src" folder should I have a folder called "com.charlesbihis.engine.notification" ? I'm not sure how I'm meant to be putting it in as it seems the package contains folders within folders!

Comment: Yes. Actually when you do that, Flash Builder will translate that to a folder structor of `com/charlesbihis/engine/notification` which is the same thing you have in your package.

Comment: I've tried to follow what you've suggested however I'm still getting errors when it comes to accessing the class http://i39.tinypic.com/2zrzype.jpg this is a screen of my code, file structure and errors

Comment: Why would you put the `com.charlesbihis.engine.notification` under `main.actionscript`?! They need to be right under your `src` folder. To give you more info, the problem is that the first line of each file in the package you are trying to use, contains a line like `package com.charlesbihis.engine.notification` and since it does not match the location of the file, Flash Builder does not recognize the file as a valid one. So you either need to change all of the `package` and `import` statements, or to re-organize the package structure as I mentioned. I think the latter is by far easier!

Comment: well I dragged the folder from the package I downloaded into the source folder and thats what it done. the structure looked like - http://i40.tinypic.com/b3wsaa.jpg however Ive selected just the asset and com folder and dragged that onto src. yet same errors - this is what it looks like after - http://i39.tinypic.com/2n00kqq.jpg

Comment: Now for `NotificationManager` and `NotificationConst` and `Notification` move your cursor to the end of each of these words and press Ctrl+Space (once instance of each word). You should get an automatically generated `import` statement on the top of your code and the errors should go away.

Comment: ah! brilliant! yeah that got rid of them all apart from - http://i39.tinypic.com/a5fcc0.jpg but i guess this is unrelated to the previous?